# Approach to handling the login attempts, php

Tags: php

I want to handle the login attempts like this :

*The ways I know to handle the attempt count is to use sessions, cookies or creating an attempt data in database;*

As I know cookies are weak because they are being stored at the client side. 
Sessions are safer to use rather than using cookies but from my research I get the result that even sessions that are created for handling login attempts can be controlled by hackers.

I decided to record the attempts to the database,

- **Keep records of the IP, attempt count, time.**
- **After 3 unsuccessful attempts I am planning to display a CAPTCHA**
- **After 2 unseccesful attempts with CAPTCHA I am planing to stop the user (which is trying from same IP) from trying login for 10 mins.**

(The reason I am not using the CAPTCHA at the beginning, because it is annoying. Nobody wants to type an extra input)

So my first question is; is it a bad idea to keep tracking the attempts by recording data because of connecting the database and checking the count of the attempts on every reloading of the loginpage can be overload the website? (I am new to web programming so if my questions are silly, pardon me)

My second question;
Is this a good way to control user by IP or is there a better way to control this?

I am waiting to hear any suggestions from you.

Comment: It is indeed a good way to attempt to secure yourself more, almost everyone big does something of that sort to control the number of attempts. Go ahead

Comment: An IP address doesn't usually correspond to one person. You might find an entire university behind a single public-facing IP address.

Comment: But, keep in mind that people can spoof their ipaddress. Ofcourse it is better to have any kind of security than nothing at all.

Comment: Increasing a database counter of some kind on every page reload doesn't cause much load, even if you are running a frequently visited page this won't make your server slow. Using a combination of user-agent and IP would be a bit better if there are more than one user connected using the same IP (gateway).

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' I agree. It is also fairly trivial to claim to have a different IP address than I actually have.  For tracking legitimate user's login attempts this may be of some small use, but to enforce security it is futile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my sites I do the following

- Limit based on IP, 5 failed attempts per IP in 1 hour, requires a captcha for 1 hour for that IP
- Limit based on user, 5 failed attempts per user in 1 hour, requires a captcha for 1 hour for that user
- Limit based on Overall failed logins, 100 overall failed in 1 hour, require a captcha for 1 hour for every log in attempt

so for example if 1.1.1.1 fails for a user called `user` all 3 counters are incremented (its implemented as a single row in the database, but the query shows all 3 values as 1). also Tweak the values depending on the size of the site.

Each time there is a captcha shown, if its required again after the 1 hour is increased by 30 minutes each time, But from the logs that has never happened yet.

Captchas like recaptcha get harder the more they are failed. So that takes care of brute forcing.

The connection to the database is a very slight over head and shouldnt even be considered when security is concerned.

I dont "reset" these counts on successful login either.

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for. Thank you. I am using recapthca, too. So if I misunderstand please correct me, for your third limit explanation; if there are 100 overal fails you require captcha for _every IP_ ?

Comment: Yes, It stops people trying passwords like `password` or `123456` for every user too. IP's are fairly cheap to buy / use. Its very rare that this rule is triggered though. The first 2 are >95%  of the time the reason a captcha is showing